# Inherit a class with private constructor? Or create a new module?

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'm using the Http type of FSharpData.

```
type Http private() = 
    ......
    static member Request(url, ?query, ?headers, ?meth, ?body, ?cookies, ?cookieContainer, ?certificate) =
    ......
```

However, I need to extend static memeber `Request` to handle cookies. I cannot inherit the class since its constructor is private.

```
type Web () =
    inherit Http() // Error
    override Request
        let ObSSOCookie = new Cookie()
        ......
```

Or I had to create a module with functions that call the static member functions? Can the module has the same name of `Http`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Http` type is a static class, because it's stateless, so it doesn't make sense to inherit from it. If you want to use cookies and maintain them across requests, you can just create a `CookieContainer` and reuse it across requests:

```
let cc = CookieContainer()
Http.RequestString("url1", cookieContainer = cc)
Http.RequestString("url2", cookieContainer = cc)
```

If you really want to, you can create a wrapper for it like this:

```
type HttpWithState() = 
    let cookies = CookieContainer()

    static member RequestString(url, ?params, ?headers, ...) =
        Http.RequestString(url, ?params = params, ?headers = headers, ..., cookieContainer = cookies)
```

and then use it like this:

```
let http = HttpWithState()
http.RequestString("url1")
http.RequestString("url2")
```

But you won't gain that much over using the `Http` type directly

Comment: Sometimes the web site (1) using javascript to set cookies (2) response a set-cookie with path = /..., then several redirect/location before reach the page with that path...

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that you can inherit from this class - this is probably a design desicision.

However, the full path to that type is

```
FSharp.Net.Http
```

so you could create your own type in something like

A.B.Http

which could call the original `http` functions and provide overrides through that method.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding static extension method to `Http` class, if it doesn't need to access privates:

```
type FSharp.Net.Http with

    static member RequestWithCookies(...) = ...
```